# The value non-undefined in GTM Preview Mode appears as Undefined in the live

Tags: variables, google-tag-manager, pixel

There is a problem that I encountered for the first time in GTM. I use DOM Ready as a trigger so that the variables pushed to the datalayer can be used in the tag. When I preview, I can see that the variables in the datalayer are full in both meta pixel helper and GTM Preview. everything is normal here.

But when we go live, these values ​​are undefined. I don't understand the reason here? How do we solve it at the same time?

Thanks.

I changed it from GTM All Pages tag to DOM Ready, but it was normal in Preview mode, but it did not work for the live version.